# Only one data from array is inserting in the database mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm inserting data from multiple inputs and only last row from array is inserting to the database.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))  

    {

        $fk_app_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
        $app_children_name = $_POST['app_children_name'];

        for( $i = 0 ; $i < count($app_children_name); $i++){
            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO applicant_children(fk_app_id, app_children_name, app_children_bday) VALUES ('$fk_app_id', '$app_children_name[$i]', '')";
        }
    }
```

Comment: You would need to execute the INSERT for each iteration of the `for` loop.  BUT you should look at using [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: That is because you keep overwriting the same variable `$sql2` in the loop, so in the end you're only left with the last `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Please use prepared statements

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `for` loop and in each step of this loop you generate a new String which has the value of a query that you would like to execute. However, inside the `for` loop you never execute your query, only when the loop finishes. For your reference:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    //This happens 100 times
}
//This happens once
```

Since your `insert` happens only once and your `insert` is defined for a single row, the behavior you experience is what one should expect seeing your code. To fix the behavior, you have several possibilities. You could define a composite `insert` to `insert` all your records in a single command, as Kris Roofe suggests, or you can actually execute your query inside your `for` loop in each step. What you do currently is analogous of writing text in a line in a notebook, erasing it, writing in the same line something else and so on and then expecting that all the previously erased texts in that line would be remembered.

Answer (score 0):

You only process the last element in your foreach loop.

Change it to,

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO applicant_children(fk_app_id, app_children_name, app_children_bday) VALUES ";
for( $i = 0 ; $i < count($app_children_name); $i++){
    $sql2 .= "('$fk_app_id', '$app_children_name[$i]', ''),";
}
trim($sql2,",");
```

Comment: its shows error and now the arrays doesn't add to the database

Comment: What error it shows?

Comment: @KrisRoofe the query probably contains some bugs that we cannot determine, not knowing what these values are and what the schema is. Upvoted.

Comment: Can you show the value of `$sql2` here.

Comment: It's unfair to downvote without reason.

Answer (score -1):

Mysql query should be executed inside the loop. Query executuon is missing in loop.

**Here is the solution :-**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))  

    {
        $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "demo");

        $fk_app_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
        $app_children_name = $_POST['app_children_name'];

        for( $i = 0 ; $i < count($app_children_name); $i++){
            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO applicant_children(fk_app_id, app_children_name, app_children_bday) VALUES ('$fk_app_id', '$app_children_name[$i]', '')";
            mysqli_query($link, $sql2);
        }
    }
?>
```